# NetSuite Advanced Approval email subsidiary issue

Tags: netsuite

I have been digging through the advanced approval scripts (specifically NSTS_GAW_WA_SendEmail) to try and figure out where this limitation comes from and am having no success. Was hoping someone could shed some light.

Basically when you submit a PO for approval, if the approver is of the same subsidiary as the transaction, they will get an email notification. I have an approver that is at the parent level subsidiary so they are not getting emails for PO's in child subsidiaries. Does anyone know of a way to make them get notifications as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, by setting the onework paramter to false, this filter isn't set in the script:

if(bOneWorld == 'T')
arrFil.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('subsidiary',null, 'anyof',record['subsidiary']));